# tcl: how to rebuid foreach_in_collection as proc in tcl

Tags: foreach, syntax, tcl, sta

for some reason, I need to rebuild foreach_in_collection (SDC command) as "foreach" in tcl.

here's snapshot code:

```
proc set_disable_timing { argv } { body ... }
proc get_cells { argv } { body ... }
```

and here has a proc "foreach_in_collection" I try to build like foreach:

```
proc foreach_in_collection {item collection script } {
  foreach collection $collection_list {
     uplevel [list set $item $collection]
     uplevel 1 $script
  }
}
```

and my source file include one code like

```
set all_cells [get_cells -hier my_cell*]
foreach_in_collection cell $all_cells {
   set_disable_timing $cell
}
```

but tcl report invalid command "-hier"
how to fix issue

Comment: You probably have not *exactly* what you showed us, and the syntax error is somewhere in the bit you didn't show. Remember to look in `$errorInfo` after an error to get a stack trace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
proc foreach_in_collection {item collection script } {
  upvar x $item
  foreach x $collection {
     uplevel $script
  }
}
```

When `x` is set to a value in foreach_in_collection, then `cell` is set to the same value in the context where foreach_in_collection is called.

Then when you `uplevel $script`, that is invoking set_disable_timing with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just:

```
interp alias {} foreach_in_collection {} foreach
```

That is: it's really just a different spelling of the command `foreach`.

The native `foreach` command is more powerful than what is provided for these shims, if you need it to be an error if the args are anything other than `item collection script` then I think you could do it like:

```
proc foreach_in_collection {item collection script} {
    tailcall ::foreach $item $collection $script
}
```